# Manual partitioning with ZFS

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, zfs

I want to partition my drive manually to use an existing ZFS file system as rootfs.
However, the manual partitioning tool doesn't allow me to choose ZFS as file system.

Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to install Ubuntu manually with debootstrap?

The reason I prefer handling partitioning myself is because I don't really like the way Ubuntu and ZSys manage ZFS. Also, the installer wants to install an ESP partition, but I don't have EFI on that system.

Comment: Are you sure that `grub` can understand ZFS? If not, how can `grub` load your system?

Comment: @waltinator `grub` can load the initramfs which will load ZFS, `/boot` is on ext4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up the OS onto ZFS in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497515/how-to-set-up-the-os-onto-zfs-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: @ArturMeinild: yes, it does, thank you!