# How to set up the OS onto ZFS in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, zfs

I want to set up a new Ubuntu 22.04.3 system with ZFS but can't find a way to tell the setup program where to mount various parts of the file system according to my plans.

Say for example I have two relatively small SSDs that I want to set up in a mirror to hold `/boot`, `/` and other basic OS stuff; and then four multi-TB HDs that I want to use in RAIDZ1 to hold `/home`, `/var`, `/data` and basically anything big.

How do I do that while installing? The setup program seems to be a stripped-down version of gparted and appears to have no awareness of ZFS, other than for the presence of an option to install "with ZFS" rather than without.

Even if I go ahead and install "with ZFS", I see no way of creating vdevs, mirrors, raids, pools, datasets and all the usual ZFS shebang until *after* the installation is complete, at which point it is rather a pain to create a mirrored pair of SSDs and move root, boot and var to it from the live system.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

*Advanced* installation of Ubuntu with "ZFS on Root" was never part of the installer (basic installation was previously an option), but with Ubuntu 22.04, it was rolled back even more with the removal of `zsys`.

However, there is a [manual installation guide](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html) in the OpenZFS documentation, that details the exact steps to do a custom ZFS installation of Ubuntu 22.04.

The guide is *way* too long to include here, but here are the marks for the individual chapters of the guide, to give an idea about its contents:

- [Step 1: Prepare The Install Environment](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-1-prepare-the-install-environment)
- [Step 2: Disk Formatting](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-2-disk-formatting)
- [Step 3: System Installation](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-3-system-installation)
- [Step 4: System Configuration](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-4-system-configuration)
- [Step 5: GRUB Installation](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-5-grub-installation)
- [Step 6: First Boot](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-6-first-boot)
- [Step 7: Full Software Installation](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-7-full-software-installation)
- [Step 8: Final Cleanup](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-8-final-cleanup)