# zfs pool is missing files after reboot

Tags: mount, 22.04, zfs

I have been (trying to) use zfs for going on a year now, but am good at screwing things up,
so please assume that I don't know what I am doing.

I have a zpool (temppool) that I wanted to mirror, so did some ill-advised cleanup
on it, to remove old files and other junk. I did Something Wrong, then went away for
a few months, and now I have this:

When I boot an Ubuntu 23.03 USB stick, and mount /home/rbe, there
are only a few Ubuntu-generated folders (19?). I.e., that folder is nearly empty.
So far, so good.

But,when I boot ubuntu, I get this:

```
ls  /temppool/dshome/
apex  bigdata  rbe  sac

sudo zfs get canmount temppool
NAME      PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
temppool  canmount  on        local
rbe@medusa:~$ sudo zfs get mountpoint temppool
NAME      PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
temppool  mountpoint  /temppool   local
rbe@medusa:~$ sudo zfs get mountpoint temppool/ds
temppool/ds   temppool/ds@  
rbe@medusa:~$ sudo zfs get mountpoint temppool/ds
NAME         PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
temppool/ds  mountpoint  none        received
rbe@medusa:~$ sudo zfs get mountpoint temppool/dshome
NAME             PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
temppool/dshome  mountpoint  /home       local
rbe@medusa:~$ sudo zfs get canmount temppool/dshome
NAME             PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
temppool/dshome  canmount  on        local
```

temppool mounts at /temppool, just so I can watch it.
dshome is leftover from an attempt to create zfs "datasets", but
it looks "mostly harmless".

I am trying to get the home folder populated:

```
ls /home
apex  bigdata  rbe  sac
```

MOST of the files in /home/rbe match those in temppool,I observe two
anomalies:

- some files/folders in /home/rbe do not exist in /temppool/dshome/rbe.
  These were NOT in /home/rbe when I booted the USB stick, so where did
  they come from?
- some files exist in /temppool/dshome/rbe, but not in /home/rbe.
  These are all files/folders that I deleted from /home/rbe in the name of cleanup,
  but why were they not deleted from the zpool?

I am sure there is a simple explanation for these anomalies, and any
suggestions are welcome!

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: You've actually provided little actionable detail. As I understand, there are some differences in file between your home dir, and a backup of this on Zpool `temppool`, correct? However, it would be good advice to list *exactly* which files that are exclusively present in each dir, preferably with long listing. Including the output of `ls -la /home/rbe` and `ls -la /temppool/dfhome/rbe` would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think a simpler way to address this problem is to ignore my specific mess, and just point me at some info on how to set up an Ubuntu /home folder under zfs, preferably mirrored.

Comment: Please [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497515/how-to-set-up-the-os-onto-zfs-in-ubuntu-22-04/1497531#1497531).